# Pass varibles to my custom email template magento

Tags: magento-1.9

How to pass the objects from observer to my email template.

**\app\code\local\Magenshop\Recipe\Model\Status.php**

```
private  function _sendStatusMail($currentStatus)
{
    $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');

    $emailTemplate->loadDefault('recipe_admin_approval');
    $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('Your order was holded');

    $salesData['email'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
    $salesData['name'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');

    $emailTemplate->setSenderName($salesData['name']);
    $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($salesData['email']);


    //Here i need to pass the 'title' value to my email template
    $emailTemplateVariables['title']  = $currentStatus->getTitle(); 
    Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);
    $emailTemplate->send($previousStatus->getCustomerEmail(), $order->getStoreName(), $emailTemplateVariables);
}


public function statusChangedApproved(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{

    $admin = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getCurrentUserId();

    if($admin !='')
    {   
        $previousStatus=Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getApproveStatus(); 
        if($previousStatus !==false)
        {       
            $currentStatus=$observer->getDataObject()->getStatus();
            if($previousStatus !==$currentStatus)
            {
                //Here instead of currentStatus, i need to pass the value of a common variable which can be reused by multiple templates
                $this->_sendStatusMail($currentStatus);

            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //notification when the recipe is submitted for approval

    }  

}
```

im getting Fatal error: Call to a member function getTitle() on string in Status.php

Comment: what is `$currentStatus`. Aparently in your script it's a string. You can just replace `$currentStatus->getTitle()` with `$currentStatus`

Comment: Seems like `_sendStatusMail()` is expecting an object and you are passing a string value.

Comment: $currentStatus gets the values either 1 or 2, my doubt is: using the same statusChangedApproved(), i need to send 3 different mails based on 3 different scenarios.. im stuck in passing the variables to the templates and parameters to the email function

Comment: You're breaking the rule of MVC by trying to pass values from a Model to the front end. Blocks are responsible for doing that not models/observers, no wonder why there are a lot of bad written modules out there.

Answer (score 1):

Add  **getProcessedTemplate**

```
$emailTemplateVariables['title']  = $currentStatus->getTitle();
$emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
```

and in send add `$storeId=null`

```
$emailTemplate->send($previousStatus->getCustomerEmail(), $order->getStoreName(), $emailTemplateVariables ,$storeId=null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
private  function _deliveryMail($order){ 
        //delivered
            $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template'); 
            $emailTemplate->loadDefault('custom_order_deliver');
            $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('Congrats! Your Order '.$order->getIncrementId().' has been successfully delivered.'); 
            // Get General email address (Admin->Configuration->General->Store Email Addresses)
            $salesData['email'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
            $salesData['name'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name'); 
            $emailTemplate->setSenderName($salesData['name']);
            $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($salesData['email']); 
            $emailTemplateVariables['username']  = $order->getCustomerFirstname() . ' ' . $order->getCustomerLastname();
            $emailTemplateVariables['order_id'] = $order->getIncrementId();
            $emailTemplateVariables['store_name'] = $order->getStoreName();
            $emailTemplateVariables['store_url'] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);
            $emailTemplate->send($order->getCustomerEmail(), $order->getStoreName(), $emailTemplateVariables); 

        }
```